# ASP.NET Interacting objects in canvas

Tags: asp.net, canvas, web, drawimage, interaction

Have a problem: I want my bubbles to move in a canvas and interact(they beat with each other and change the direction of move). I learned how to move them, but cannot make them interact. Object is an image that I draw with drawImage(,,).

How can I make it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on this website:

http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769